# ArgumentOutOfRange exception in EPPlus when copying worksheet to new workbook

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

I want to copy a worksheet from a template workbook to a new workbook. I've used this code in other projects and it works fine, but now I have an issue with an excel workbook, but I don't know what is wrong. Here's the code:

```
byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(source);
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(file))
{
    var package = new ExcelPackage(ms);

    var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

    var copyPackage = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(destination));

    // the following line causes a ArgumentOutOfRangeException
    copyPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheet.Name, worksheet);
    copyPackage.Save();
}
```

This is the exception's stacktrace (apologies, in german):

```
Der Index lag außerhalb des Bereichs. Er darf nicht negativ und kleiner als die Sammlung sein.
Parametername: index
   bei System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
   bei OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelStyle.get_XfId()
   bei OfficeOpenXml.ExcelStyles.CreateNamedStyle(String name, ExcelStyle Template)
   bei OfficeOpenXml.ExcelStyles.CloneStyle(ExcelStyles style, Int32 styleID, Boolean isNamedStyle, Boolean allwaysAdd)
   bei OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheets.CloneCells(ExcelWorksheet Copy, ExcelWorksheet added)
   bei OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheets.Add(String Name, ExcelWorksheet Copy)
   bei CopyExcel.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\spikes\CopyExcel\CopyExcel\Program.cs:Zeile 26.
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem. Some unrelated points: you should use `using` statments when dealing with ExcelPackage because it's a `IDisposable`. Also, Why you load the file to an array, put in an MemoryStream to pass to ExcelPackage instead of passing a FileInfo with the path?

Comment: Are you sure your file has two worksheets and you are copying 2nd one?Maybe change it to   package.Workbook.Worksheets[0]; A safer way would be using worksheet name  package.Workbook.Worksheets[<WorkSheetName>]

Comment: @Magnetron Thanks. Apologies, the original code (from an ASP.NET project uses using-statements along with the excel package). The other thing with the MemoryStream is a good point for improvement but solves not the problem. 

It looks, as if styles in the copied worksheet are not correctly copied along with the worksheet itself for any reason.

Comment: @Sanjay  Correct. Using worksheet names is a better idea and this is also what is implemented. As an example here index was easier to use. And yes, the worksheet does exist.

Comment: @Sanjay worksheets in Epplus are base 1, so OP is selecting the first one.